# Persisting URL query string with jQuery breaks anchors

Tags: jquery, anchor, query-string

I use the folowing jQuery script to persist a certain query string on my whole website. However, it breaks html anchors as it appends the string a second time to the URL once a html anchor link is called

example:

expected behavior: www.example.com/?string=value ---> www.example.com/?string=value#anchor

actual result: www.example.com/?string=value ---> www.example.com/?string=value#anchor?string=value

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var persistedQueryParam = getParameterByName('STRINGNAME');

if (persistedQueryParam && persistedQueryParam.length > 0) {
$('a[href]').each(function () {
  var elem = $(this);
  var href = elem.attr('href');
  elem.attr('href', href + (href.indexOf('?') != -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'STRINGNAME=' + persistedQueryParam);
});
}
});
```

Any solutions for this? I tried checking for hash via href.indexOf('#') but couldn't get it to work. It seems like I cannot check the URL as the anchor is added on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution: problem was, that html anchors are also inside href. I solved the problem via excluding links beginning with #:

```
$('a[href]').not('a[href^="#"]').each
```

This means, however, links containing url and an anchor (like www.example.com/page#anchor) would load the page, but not jump to the anchor. Not relevant to me, though.